# Probability: rolling of a dice two times and showing that two events are independent

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let event A be the probability of throwing a 2 or a 5 after the first throw.
Let event B be the probability of the sum of the first throw and this throw (the second throw) be bigger or equal to 7.

Are events A and B independent?

My reasoning:
If they are independent then we have to show this condition:
$P(B∩A) = P(A)*P(B)$ is fulfilled.

$P(A)=\dfrac{\text{2}}{6}=\dfrac{\text{1}}{3}$

$P(B∩A) = \dfrac{\text{1}}{6}*\dfrac{\text{2}}{3}+\dfrac{\text{1}}{6}*\dfrac{\text{5}}{6}=\dfrac{\text{1}}{4}$

$P(B|A) = \dfrac{\text{P(B∩A)}}{P(A)}= \dfrac{\text{3}}{4}$

Law of total probability:
$P(B)=P(B|A)P(A)+P(B|A^*)P(A^*)$
From that I can calculate P(B) after calculating $P(B|A^*) =\dfrac{\text{13}}{36} $. Then I can check my first condition.

Are my probabilities correct and is this the way to do it?

Comment: I think you made a mistake in the second factor of the first term of $P(B\cap A)$

Comment: I will redo it and see what I come up with :)

Comment: The probability of $\ge 7$ is, after a short calculation, $21/36$. Now you need the probability of $A\cap B$. This is done as in your calculation, but the $2/3$ should be $2/6$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas How did you calculate the probability of B?

Comment: @Mathguy007 The same way as for $A\cap B$, but this time for all 6 values the second roll can take.

Comment: @GrahamKemp I get the same but I am wondering what I do wrong when I use the law of total probability. I should get the same answer

Comment: @GrahamKemp arggh I got it now :) thanks to all for the help! :)

Comment: You probably know the probabilities of various sums when we toss two dice. Add up from $7$ to $12$. Actually I used a shortcut, we know the probability of sum $7$ is $6/36$. So the probability of not $7$ is $30/36$. By symmetry the probability of $\gt 7$ is $15/36$. Add $6/36$ to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To throw a 2 on the second roll, and have the sum of both rolls equal or exceed 7, you need to throw a 5 or 6 on the first roll.

$$\mathsf P(A\cap B) = \frac 1 6\frac 2{\color{red}{6}}+\frac 1 6\frac 5 6 = \frac 7 {36}$$

In a similar manner we can calculate $$\mathsf P(B) = \frac 1 6 \frac{6+5+4+3+2+1}6= \frac 7{12}$$

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Ahaa I got that too this time :) I get that they are independent since I calculated $P(B) = 34/36=17/18$